# Simple hibernate using command prompt

Tags: hibernate, jar, command-prompt

I have programmed a simple hibernate app which leaves me with errors. The following is my code.

**Contact.java**

```
public class Contact {
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String email;
 private long id;


 public String getEmail() {
  return email;
 }


 public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
 }


 public String getLastName() {
  return lastName;
 }


 public void setEmail(String string) {
  email = string;
 }


 public void setFirstName(String string) {
  firstName = string;
 }


 public void setLastName(String string) {
  lastName = string;
 }


 public long getId() {
  return id;
 }


 public void setId(long l) {
  id = l;
 }

}
```

**FirstExample.java**

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;



public class FirstExample {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Session session = null;

  try{

  SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
  session =sessionFactory.openSession();

  System.out.println("Inserting Record");
  Contact contact = new Contact();
  contact.setId(3);
  contact.setFirstName("Tausif");
  contact.setLastName("rahmathullah");
  contact.setEmail("t.r@vl.net");
  session.save(contact);
  System.out.println("updated");
  }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
    if(session!=null){
     session.flush();
     session.close();
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/simpHiber</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <mapping resource="contact.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**contact.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="Contact" table="CONTACT">
  <id name="id" type="long" column="ID" >
   <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>

  <property name="firstName">
   <column name="FIRSTNAME" />
  </property>
  <property name="lastName">
   <column name="LASTNAME"/>
  </property>
  <property name="email">
   <column name="EMAIL"/>
  </property>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Error**

```
D:\TausifProjects\simpHiber>java FirstExample
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:197)
    at FirstExample.main(FirstExample.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

**Jar files in the buildpath**

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate3.jar
hibernate3.3.1-slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
javassist-3.4.ga.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.0-bin.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.5.jar
slf4j-jdk14-1.5.2-sources.jar
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include slf4j-log4j.jar, then you must also include the log4j jar. Slf4j is a logging facade, which means it gives you a uniform interface to multiple other logging APIs.

Comment: the program works.. but not able to update the table with information  I am passing through the object. It created the table though..

Comment: Can you share code ? You can start a new thread for the same .

Answer (score 0):

Add log4j.jar on your classpath or remove slf4j-log4j12-1.5.5.jar from the classpath

Comment: I added the jar file. But am still getting other errors.

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: name
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.<init (Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:75)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:75)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:197)
        at FirstExample.main(FirstExample.java:15)

Comment: share the latest errors. BTW you need to add log4j.properties or xml file when you use log4j jar.

Comment: Please also tel me if the other coding is correct or not! Thanks you so much.

Comment: Looks like mismatch between version of slf4j-log4j12-1.5.5.jar and log4j jar that you used.Your code looks ok to me.

Comment: which version should I use then.. i tried different versions of the jar files as well